# Does the DISQUS.reset javascript function have any error handling?

Tags: javascript, api, disqus

I'm wondering if there is any way to add a callback on error to DISQUS.reset javascript function.

Does anyone know if there is more detailed doco on the reset function? Or if there is an error callback?

The only example I can find [1] cites this code:

```
DISQUS.reset({
  reload: true,
  config: function () {
    this.page.identifier = identifier
    this.page.url = url
  }
})
```

References:
[1] https://help.disqus.com/customer/en/portal/articles/472107-using-disqus-on-ajax-sites

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given the Disqus support page was last updated January 2014 I suspect they are not looking to put any more effort into supporting single page web apps.

In the end we decided not to use Disqus as it wasn't flexible enough for our customers including:

- Inability to hide/show likes.
- Although possible to configure "sort of" anonymous comments, their forms try to push the users to register, which some of our customers didn't want.
- Heavy Javascript
- Inability to hide/show suggestions

Comment: I'm going through the process of trying to figure out how to debug or solve issues I'm having with Disqus in an SPA. Don't think there is any error handling callbacks. I'm getting a lot of 'unsafe-inline'  'script-dynamic' warnings in console in Firefox/Edge, and every site using Disqus I've look at also has them - but can not find any info

Comment: do you have any alternative for discuss? I face same problem here.. thanks

Comment: @taufardh There are quite a few options like https://www.hotjar.com/ and https://www.zendesk.com/ The ones I've seen require you to add a script tag to your page, and then they place a widget on the page and have full control of it. These products generally have their own admin dashboards to manage the "customer experience". Further, for callbacks they way this pretty much works now is you create something like AWS lambda functions, and their system triggers the API endpoints.